# How to calculate percentage of sparsity for a numpy array/matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have the following 10 by 5 numpy array/matrix, which has a number of `NaN` values:

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.],
       [  1.,   1.,   0.,  nan,  nan],
       [  0.,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.],
       [  1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

How does one measure exactly how sparse this array is? Is there a simply function in numpy for measuring the percentage of missing values?

Comment: how about this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html?

Comment: `sparse.html` documents a package that creates sparse matrices, but I don't see a 'sparsity' measure function.  There sparsity means many `0` values, not a few `nan` values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
np.isnan(a).sum()
```

gives the number of `nan` values, in this example 8.

```
np.prod(a.shape)
```

is the number of values, here 50.  Their ratio should give the desired value.

```
In [1081]: np.isnan(a).sum()/np.prod(a.shape)
Out[1081]: 0.16
```

You might also find it useful to make a masked array from this

```
In [1085]: a_ma=np.ma.masked_invalid(a)
In [1086]: print(a_ma)
[[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0]
 [1.0 1.0 0.0 -- --]
 [0.0 -- 1.0 -- --]
 [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 --]
 [-- -- 1.0 1.0 1.0]
 [0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0]
 [1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]]
```

The number of valid values then is:

```
In [1089]: a_ma.compressed().shape
Out[1089]: (42,)
```

Answer (score 18):

**Definition:**

[image]

### Code for a general case:

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import count_nonzero
import numpy as np

# create dense matrix
A = array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [99, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]])

#If you have Nan
A = np.nan_to_num(A,0)

print(A)
#[[ 1  1  0  1  0  0]
# [ 1  0  2  0  0  1]
# [99  0  0  2  0  0]]

# calculate sparsity
sparsity = 1.0 - ( count_nonzero(A) / float(A.size) )
print(sparsity)
```

**Results:**

```
0.555555555556
```

Comment: If A_sparse is a sparse matrix, then correct expression is  `sparsity = 1.0 - ( A_sparse.count_nonzero() / float(A_sparse.toarray().size) )`. Using float(A_sparse.size) would give incorrect sparsity of 0 for all sparse matrices.

Comment: Actually float(A.toarray().size) and float(A.size) is **not**  same if A is a sparse matrix. This is so because size for a sparse matrix gives the number of entries corresponding to non-zero elements. Also, np.prod(A_sparse.shape) is better than using A_sparse.toarray().size because the later one involves an computationally expensive step of converting a sparse matrix to dense martix.

Answer (score 5):

Measuring the percentage of missing values has already explained by 'hpaulj'.

I am taking the first part of your question, Assuming array has Zero's and Non-Zero's...

Sparsity refers to Zero values and density refers to Non-Zero values in array.
Suppose your array is X, 
get count of non-zero values:

`non_zero = np.count_nonzero(X)`

total values in X:

`total_val = np.product(X.shape)`

Sparsity will be -

`sparsity = (total_val - non_zero) / total_val`

And Density will be -

`density = non_zero / total_val`

The sum of Sparsity and Density must equal to 100%...

Comment: Thanks for this! This is helpful